# DATEADD function not allowed in Redshift error

Tags: amazon-redshift

I am trying to to run the following:

```
DROP TABLE IF exists timestamp_15min;
Create TEMP TABLE timestamp_15min AS 
SELECT 
    dateadd(minute,min_15,dateadd(hour,hours,dateadd(day,days,start_date::timestamp))) AS date_time,
    TO_CHAR(date_time,'HH24') || ':' || TO_CHAR(date_time,'MI')  || ':' || '00' AS mins15
FROM 
    (SELECT trunc(sysdate-14) AS start_date)
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT generate_series(0,14,1) AS days)
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT generate_series(0,24,1) AS hours)
CROSS JOIN (SELECT generate_series(0,60,15) as min_15)
;
```

And I get this error

```
Specified types or functions (one per INFO message) not supported on Redshift tables.
```

If I remove the the `DROP` AND `CREATE TABLE`, and just run the below with `SELECT` it works fine

```
SELECT 
    dateadd(minute,min_15,dateadd(hour,hours,dateadd(day,days,start_date::timestamp))) AS date_time,
    TO_CHAR(date_time,'HH24') || ':' || TO_CHAR(date_time,'MI')  || ':' || '00' AS mins15
FROM 
    (SELECT trunc(sysdate-14) AS start_date)
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT generate_series(0,14,1) AS days)
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT generate_series(0,24,1) AS hours)
CROSS JOIN (SELECT generate_series(0,60,15) as min_15)
```

Can someone explain what function or type is Redshift blocking ?

Comment: There is no `dateadd` function in Oracle, the SELECT should fail. Do you use Oracle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`generate_series` is not supported in queries that reference Redshift user tables. It will work when querying catalog tables only.

You can use the `ROW_NUMBER()` function to generate a series instead.